# How to prevent this conflict in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, code-first

Hi friends i am new in entity framework .
i am using entity framework code first approach.
i created a self join table.

```
public class A
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, MaxLength(20),Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? Parent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public virtual A FkA{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public virtual ICollection<A> FkAl{ get; set; }
    }
```

Now it created table with no problem and i am able to insert the data .
but the problem is that .

> Suppose i inserted 3 row like

```
   Name1 with NULL Parent 
   Name2 with Name1 Parent 
   Name3 with Name2 Parent
```

it allow me to insert in that way and that's fine

but if i update this in that way like .

```
   Name1 with Name3  Parent 
   Name2 with Name1 Parent 
   Name3 with Name1 Parent
```

it give me no error . but you can see that Name1 and Name3 are both inside each other .

cos it is an self join table what is the best way to check right Hierarchy .

> like higher can not go in lower

Please help me on this .

i tried on lots of things and got the a way with apply foreach loop on ICollection and this allow me to check this but i think it took lots of time when Hierarchy go dipper . so please provide me the best way to do this .

thanks

Comment: your update means `Name3` is parent of `Name1` and `Name1` is also a parent of `Name3`? weird.

Comment: @Hopeless yes and that should not happens

Comment: to prevent that, there are 2 cases: First when setting parent for some `A`, be sure it's not any child of `A`. Second when adding child for some `A`, be sure it's not parent of `A`. You need to do that manually of course. You also need to check recursively, well I can imagine how intensive it is.

Comment: @Hopeless but what if some on add A in B , B in C , C in  D , D in E , and E in A . now E should not go in A cos it is a lower value now how can i check it .? please help me on this . i am trying it from lest night and i am in problem now .

Comment: That's what I said about ***recursive***. Currently doing so may impact the performance much depending on the depth and size of your tree. I guess you can try creating another column called `Ancestor`. Now the relationship is `many-many`: one item can have many ancestors and one ancestor can have many items. So you need to add 2 more nav properties (of collection) such as one called `Descendants` and one called `Ancestors`. That way you can check for circular reference without using recursion (just 1 level of depth). Adding/removing items then may be trickier.

Answer (score 0):

Only having a parent-child relationship does not mean a table contains a valid table or tables (forest)

You are essentially looking for a way to enforce a valid tree (Or forest) structure on your table.

In EF, the best thing you can do is arguably what you did.
In sql server, however, you can do much better, see for instance [Hierrachical Data-Sql Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx#BKMK_EnforcingTrees) section: Enforcing a Tree. Essentialy, it combines a hierrchyid primary key and a computed, persisted parent foreign key.

Please check if the plugin implementations for hierarchyid in EF can come to rescue.

That being said, I can guess that what you encounter is the first in a series of problems you're going to face because of the lack of a quick way to query your data in a hierarchy-aware manner. For instance, lets say you all ancestors of a given entry: All you can do is to loop through parts.

Worse: how you get all descendants of a given entry? This one is going to be more complex.

Actually, if you had a quick query to find descendants of an entry, you could check if the new parent is one of them and all was good.

So my suggestion is that if you have a serious hierarchy, it is totally worth the effort to add some hierarchyid column to the table.

Comment: It min there is no easy way to do this ?

Comment: For a rapid fix and not a permanent one, I suggest you implement a function in Sql server to ckeck the validity of your data, given two entries. It should make sure that the second entry is not already a descendant of the first entry. It will be marginally faster than doing the same check in EF. This will give you some time to implement a cleaner approach.

Comment: @Alirezaok let me try this .